# Intuitive interpretation: (sort of) Autocorrelation of Autoregressive Process

Tags: interpretation, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Suppose I have a zero-mean, stationary AR(4)-process given by:

$$θ_t=δ_1 θ_{t-1}+δ_2 θ_{t-2}+δ_3 θ_{t-3}+δ_4 θ_{t-4}+u_t = \sum_{p=1}^{P=4} δ_p θ_{t-p} + u_t$$
where $u_t{\sim}N(0,σ_u^2)$

As an exercise I was asked to give an inutitive interpretation of the following related term:

$$φ_1(δ_1δ_2 + δ_2δ_3+δ_3δ_4)+ φ_2 (δ_1δ_3+δ_2δ_4 )+φ_3 (δ_1 δ_4)$$
where $φ_k$ is the $k$-th order autocorrelation.

Honestly, I am at a loss. A sum over $φ_k$ could be considered the area below the autocorrelation function, I guess. But what about the weighting with the permutations of the ar-coefficients?

P.S. No cheating involved as the exercise is not graded.